# How can I fix my Dr Who downloading script?

Tags: bash, sed

Here is the background to this script:

A year or two ago I tried to automate downloading Dr Who by mixing Bash Scripting and the `get-iplayer` program. This was both an exercise in scripting and wanting to watch Dr Who. I've never gotten iPlayer to work, and I'm too forgetful to run `get-iplayer` each time.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Export programme names; make sure PROG is a search term that only brings up the shows you want
export PROG="Doctor Who"
export SHORT="Dr"

#Get the info you want into some text files, named after the SHORT keyword
(ls /home/$USER/Videos/iPlayer/"$PROG" | grep Doctor) >/home/$USER/Videos/iPlayer/.Code/"$SHORT"Hist.tmp
get_iplayer --listformat="<pid>: <name> - <episode>" --search="$PROG:" >/home/$USER/Videos/iPlayer/.Code/"$SHORT"Curr.tmp 

#Tidy the first file to get rid of underscores 
#then egrep to suck out the pid...schluuurp

sed -i 's/_/ /g' ./"$SHORT"Hist.tmp
#replace the underscores in the file name with spaces
egrep  -o '[bp]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9a-z]{4}' ./"$SHORT"Hist.tmp >./"$SHORT"Hist.txt
rm ./"$SHORT"Hist.tmp
egrep  -o '[bp]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9a-z]{4}' ./"$SHORT"Curr.tmp >./"$SHORT"Curr.txt
rm ./"$SHORT"Curr.tmp
#'b[0-9a-z]{7}' is the regex for the pid 
#--I've edited this as the pid regex no longer matches the above

sort ./"$SHORT"Curr.txt -o ./"$SHORT"Curr.txt
sort ./"$SHORT"Hist.txt -o ./"$SHORT"Hist.txt
#get things in order

diff ./"$SHORT"Curr.txt ./"$SHORT"Hist.txt > ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt
rm ./"$SHORT"Curr.txt ./"$SHORT"Hist.txt
sed -i 's/[^ ]* //1' ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt 
sed -i '1d' ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt
sed -i 's/---/\n/g'./"$SHORT"Diff.txt #<---this doesn't work?
sed '/^$/q' 

#get-iplayer --listformat="<index>" --field=pid $(cat "$SHORT"Diff.txt |  tr '\n' ' ') >./"$SHORT"Diff.txt
#sed -i '1,6d' ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt

#sed -i '/^$/,$ d' ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt

#get-iplayer --get $(cat "$SHORT"Diff.txt |  tr '\n' ' ') --output="/home/$LOGNAME/Videos/iPlayer/$PROG" --force
```

Now I wouldn't be posting here if this worked. There are a few issues:

- The sed line I pointed out `sed -i 's/---/\n/g'./"$SHORT"Diff.txt` give me this error
  `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to` s'`
- The `diff` program doesn't seem to pick out the current `pid` I don't know what changed since it worked before.

Is anyone able to help me fix this script?

#### edit

As requested
`uname; sed --version`
produces
`Linux`
`GNU sed version 4.2.1`

And putting `set -x` in:

```
+ export 'PROG=Doctor Who'
+ PROG='Doctor Who'
+ export SHORT=Dr
+ SHORT=Dr
+ ls '/home/craig/Videos/iPlayer/Doctor Who'
+ grep Doctor
+ get_iplayer '--listformat=<pid>: <name> - <episode>' '--search=Doctor Who:'

+ sed -i 's/_/ /g' ./DrHist.tmp
+ egrep -o '[bp]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9a-z]{4}' ./DrHist.tmp
+ rm ./DrHist.tmp
+ egrep -o '[bp]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9a-z]{4}' ./DrCurr.tmp
+ rm ./DrCurr.tmp
+ sort ./DrCurr.txt -o ./DrCurr.txt
+ sort ./DrHist.txt -o ./DrHist.txt
+ diff ./DrCurr.txt ./DrHist.txt
+ rm ./DrCurr.txt ./DrHist.txt
+ sed -i 's/[^ ]* //1' ./DrDiff.txt
+ sed -i 1d ./DrDiff.txt
+ sed -i 's/---/\n/g./DrDiff.txt'
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
+ sed '/^$/q'
```

And the output:

```
p00wqr1 <--one file


b00sj9q <--the contents of the other file.
b00sj9s
b010tb7
b010y5l
b0110g4
b011884
b011fnd
b011lqw
```

The input of the `diff` is the first line of output and the lines beginning `b0...`. Why isn't it working when it did before?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of the script, it will print out each line as it executes. Paste the results here.

Comment: edit your post to include the output from `uname; sed --version`. Some sed versions support `\n` as a replacement pattern and some don't. If you changed versions of sed or your OS from when this used to work, version differences are likely your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I'll do that when I get home tonight

Comment: @BartonChittenden I did *not* know that. I'll do that at home tonight.

Comment: now look at what your `set -x` trace is showing you ;-) `+ sed -i 's/---/\n/g./DrDiff.txt'` .. That doesn't look right, does it? (compare it to the line above). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I've fixed that but my out put is still..well I'll show you my output.

Comment: Isn't the `diff` happening before the broken sed line? Or is the broken sed line now ruled out as a possible source of problem? Please consider editing your question to include expected sample output. Don't have time to guess right now. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Your diff was the wrong way round. So it wasn't finding the right set of PIDs. Here is the working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Export programme names; make sure PROG is a search term that only brings up the shows you want
#set -x

export PROG="Doctor Who"
export SHORT="Dr"

#Get the info you want into some text files, named after the SHORT keyword
(ls /home/$USER/Videos/iPlayer/"$PROG" | grep "$PROG") >/home/$USER/Videos/iPlayer/.Code/"$SHORT"Hist.tmp
get_iplayer --listformat="<pid>: <name> - <episode>" --search="$PROG:" >/home/$USER/Videos/iPlayer/.Code/"$SHORT"Curr.tmp 

#Tidy the first file to get rid of underscores 
#then egrep to suck out the pid...schluuurp

sed -i 's/_/ /g' ./"$SHORT"Hist.tmp
#replace the underscores in the file name with spaces
egrep  -o '[bp]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9a-z]{4}' ./"$SHORT"Hist.tmp >./"$SHORT"Hist.txt
rm ./"$SHORT"Hist.tmp
egrep  -o '[bp]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9a-z]{4}' ./"$SHORT"Curr.tmp >./"$SHORT"Curr.txt
rm ./"$SHORT"Curr.tmp
#'b[0-9a-z]{7}' is the regex for the pid 
#--I've edited this as the pid regex no longer matches the above

sort ./"$SHORT"Curr.txt -o ./"$SHORT"Curr.txt
sort ./"$SHORT"Hist.txt -o ./"$SHORT"Hist.txt
#get things in order

diff ./"$SHORT"Hist.txt ./"$SHORT"Curr.txt > ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt
rm ./"$SHORT"Curr.txt ./"$SHORT"Hist.txt
sed -i 's/[^ ]* //1' ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt 
sed -i '1d' ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt
sed -i 's/---/\n/g' ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt
sed '/^$/q' #<---magic?

#get the <index> from the PID
get-iplayer --listformat="<index>" --field=pid $(cat "$SHORT"Diff.txt |  tr '\n' ' ') >./"$SHORT"Diff.txt
#Sed is a magical beast
sed -i '1,6d' ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt
sed -i '/^$/,$ d' ./"$SHORT"Diff.txt
#Run get-iplayer over for each of the PIDs found, putting them in a video folder
get-iplayer --get $(cat "$SHORT"Diff.txt |  tr '\n' ' ') --output="/home/$LOGNAME/Videos/iPlayer/$PROG" --force
```